# Converting ggplot2 grouped barchart to a plotly graph results in disappearance of some bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

When I want to convert a barchart with ggplotly to a plotly graph two bars disappear.

I also tried creating the grouped bar graph the plotly way, but that gave the same result as well.

Here is the dataset:

| title | rank | date | artist | streams | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All I Want for Christmas Is You | 1 | 12/25/2020 | Mariah Carey | 13573228 | 2020 |
| Last Christmas | 2 | 12/25/2020 | Wham! | 12415012 | 2020 |
| Rockin' Around The Christmas Tree | 3 | 12/25/2020 | Brenda Lee | 10893485 | 2020 |
| All I Want for Christmas Is You | 1 | 12/25/2019 | Mariah Carey | 9268219 | 2019 |
| Last Christmas | 2 | 12/25/2019 | Wham! | 7587790 | 2019 |
| Dance Monkey | 3 | 12/25/2019 | Tones And I | 5890362 | 2019 |
| All I Want for Christmas Is You | 1 | 12/25/2018 | Mariah Carey | 8449779 | 2018 |
| Last Christmas | 2 | 12/25/2018 | Wham! | 6914425 | 2018 |
| Rockin' Around The Christmas Tree | 3 | 12/25/2018 | Brenda Lee | 5786608 | 2018 |
| All I Want for Christmas Is You | 1 | 12/25/2017 | Mariah Carey | 6467590 | 2017 |
| Last Christmas | 2 | 12/25/2017 | Wham! | 5122502 | 2017 |
| Do They Know It's Christmas? - 1984 Version | 3 | 12/25/2017 | Band Aid | 3699892 | 2017 |

Here is the code I used:

```
top_tracks_plot <- ggplot(data = top_xmastracks_spotify, aes(x = year, y = streams, fill = ordered(title))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")

ggplotly(top_tracks_plot)
```

[image: GGPLOT2]

[image: PLOTLY]

As you can see did two songs disappear in the plotly graph. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: it works well on my local, what's your `plotly` version ?

Comment: Version 4.9.4. But I am trying to run it in a kaggle kernel using Rmarkdown. In my local R studio it is working as well, I just discovered. So it has to do something with the kaggle environment.